Change MediaRecorder output file based on time limit instead of file size
I'm trying to modify the MediaRecorder API to change the output file when a specific time limit is reached instead of relying on the file size limit. I haven't found many resources for this scenario, so I thought of asking for help on Stackoverflow.
What I want to achieve:
Record video using MediaRecorder.
Change the output file when a specific time limit is reached without stopping and restarting the recording.
I'm open to any suggestions or guidance on how to get started with modifying MediaRecorder itself to implement this feature.
Additional details:
I'm using Android as the development platform.
I've already explored using MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener but it doesn't seem to provide the functionality I need.
I appreciate any help or insights you can provide.
I tried modifying the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener to change the output file based on the time limit.

OnInfoListener has a max duration and a max file size.  That doesn’t work for you?

No, because when it comes to size, there are two events, one of which is before reaching the required size, which allows me to change the output file. As for the time limit, there is only one event that fires when I stop recording and I need to restart the recording again. This does not suit my application that I am currently working on.

I need the same behavior in terms of time to change the output file without interrupting the recording

without interrupting the recording For MediaRecorder, it can't do that.

@JianweiSun-MSFT Where do I start to modify MediaRecorder? I did not find anything in the source code provided by Google that could be modified

See this case: Is it possible to change MediaRecorder's stream?.

@JianweiSun-MSFT  I thank you very much for your effort, but perhaps the mediarecorder they are talking about there has something to do with the web or JavaScript, as I understand the discussion there.
What I wanted to ask about here is the Android SDK's MediaRecorder
